# What's the proper way to output an array of objects in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am knew to react and can't seem to get past this bit of code. I have some data that I would like to output to the dom, but am unsure of how to do that. Can anyone help?

Sample data:
  App.js :

```
       constructor(props){
       super(props);
        this.state.foods = [
        {
        recipe: '1 cup egg, 4 cups...',
        time: 42
        },
        {
        recipe: '1 tbsp butter, 2 cups...',
        time: 120
        }
        ]
       }
   `render(){
    <div className='App'>
       <Recipes data={this.state.foods} />
     </div>
`
```

How would I properly go about outputting this in my Recipes component? I've tried a forEach loop over the contents of the this.props.foods array but cannot get it to work, any help would be great.

```
The output I would like to see is:

    <H2> 1 cup egg, 4 cups...</h2>
    <h3> Time: 42 minutes </h2> 
    <br>
    <H2> 1 tbsp butter, 2 cups...</h2>
    <h3> Time: 120 minutes </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), e.g.:

```
{this.props.data.map(food => <div>
  <h2>{food.recipe}</h2>
  <h3>Time: {food.time} minute{food.time !== 1 ? 's' : ''}</h3>
</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea way is to make use of a map as @Jonny also suggested, however to add to his answer whenever you map over an array you should be specifying a key to the generated JSX elements. Its helps improve performance of react since React identifies the change by key, if key is the same the element won't rerender.

The idea key is a unique attribute other than index , since index can change if you delete an item from middle of array. However if not other option is available you can go with it as well

```
{this.props.data.map((food, index) => <div key={index}>
  <h2>{food.recipe}</h2>
  <h3>Time: {food.time} minute{food.time !== 1 ? 's' : ''}</h3>
</div>}
```